# On change select value update href link value

Tags: javascript, php

I have a select as below. Below it I got a link where current the eID value I fixed to a session value. What I would require is to change it dynamically when I select the eID value. I know in my getMList function I can get the value but how to update this portion of the codes window.open('addAdSelect.php?eID=' such that the select eID is updated accordingly.

```
<select class='select' id='eID' name='eID' onchange='getMList(this.value)'>

</select>

    <tr>
            <td>                

            </td>
            <td>
              <a href='#' onclick="window.open('addAdSelect.php?eID=<?php echo $_SESSION['eID']; ?>', 'ADS','width=500, height=750,scrollbars=yes')">Select List</a>
            </td>
        </tr>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would go with this approach. Change link HTML to this one:

```html
<a href="#" id="link" data-eid="<?php echo $_SESSION['eID']; ?>" 
   onclick="window.open('addAdSelect.php?eID=' + this.getAttribute('data-eid'), 'ADS','width=500, height=750,scrollbars=yes')">Select List</a>
```

Then in change `getMList` to update link `data-eid` attribute:

```
function getMList(eid) {
    document.getElementById('link').setAttribute('data-eid', eid);
    // ...
}
```

So the idea is that on select `onchange` event you update `data-eid` attribute of the link.

#### Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/0529cto3/